# Why isn't there an electrical potential?

Tags: power-supply, voltage

I have two different DC power supplies (6 and 12 volts, let's call them A and B). They connect to the wall and provide a negative and a positive terminal each.

I tried to measure the voltage between the positive terminal of A and the negative terminal of B and measured 0V.

I don't understand why the potential difference between the + and - terminals of different power supplies is 0V. One could say that they don't complete a circuit, but they should, they both come from the mains of my house.

Can someone please explain me what I am thinking wrongly?

Thanks in advance,
Calvin

Answer (score 4):

They come from the mains, but they're isolated from it by a transformer. You're correct about the complete circuit, because that the condition to have a potential difference (just say voltage difference, that's also OK).

If you would take a transformer and measure the resistance between a contact on the primary and a contact on the secondary you'll see that the resistance is very high, almost infinite. There's no closed circuit. If you would measure the voltage between the pins of power supply A you would have a closed circuit: from one pin through the multimeter's resistance back to the other pin.

A closed circuit is the condition.

**edit**
However! Note that this is for DC. AC signals can pass though transformers and capacitors, which also would block DC.

Comment: "Insulated" or "isolated"?

Comment: @ThePhoton - sorry, I'm not a native English speaker. In Dutch we use the same word for both, so this is a bit confusing. Both insulated and isolated then? Feel free to edit my answer if you think it's necessary.

Comment: @stevenvh, there is insulation that provides the isolation but it would be standard to say it is isolated as mains is still powering it but they do not have a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer your question with non-technical, layman way of describing with plain English.

Even your different DC power supplies are getting power from mains (A/C wall outlet) of your house they can't create any 'close circuit' condition due to isolation inside both of your DC power supplies. Most of common AC to DC power supplies have step down/up transformer inside to provide electric isolation.

To make electric current flow ether in or out from a DC power supply, you have to provide opposite path via same DC circuit inside same power supply unite. Without electron flow you will not have any 'voltage/potential difference' between two point. Your connection of negative and positive terminal from two different DC power supply will act same like connecting one positive terminal from one battery and other negative terminal from other different battery.

However, if your power supply is some kind of A/C power adapter, you will get voltage reading regardless of different physical unite. AC power do flow ANY possible path it can find. That's why connecting any AC powered device 'live/positive' terminal to A/C mains and 'negative/neutral' directly earth ground will run all most all of time you try.